# HTML DOM extracting content by Parrent to Child relation

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to parse the HTML DOM, using PHP;

I have a string PN, and I want to detect the Parrent of the DOM Element where PN has been found as content;

Then, with the Parrent Element found, i need all the Childrens of those Elements;

All the other DOM Elements that are not under the Parrent structure, must be ignored;

Comment: To get some help, you have to show some code and some research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i managed to write, but i dont know what to write after $node-> in order to obtain the element (h1,h2,div,span) ...

```
//start xpath
// Create new DOM object:
$dom = new DomDocument();
// Load HTML code:
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*');
$data = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $data[] = $node->textContent;
}
if( count( $data ) > 0 )
{
echo '<br/>xpath<br/>';
print_r( $data );
}
//stop xpath
```